# how to build count and say problem in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to solve the below problem in JavaScript

**The count-and-say sequence is the sequence of integers beginning as follows:**

```
1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221, ...
1 is read off as one 1 or 11.
11 is read off as two 1s or 21.

21 is read off as one 2, then one 1 or 1211.

Given an integer n, generate the nth sequence.

Note: The sequence of integers will be represented as a string.

Example:

if n = 2,
the sequence is 11.
```

So I want to create a function which pass `N` integer and gives it value

Here is my code:

```
let countAndSay = function (A) {
    if (A == 1) return "1"
    if (A == 2) return "11"
    let str ="11"
    if(A > 2){
     // count 
    }
}
```

I don't understand the logic for how to build this.

Comment: See also [https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence#JavaScript](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence#JavaScript) There's even a direct method there in D for very long sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be able to dynamically determine the number and type of chunks a string has, which can be done pretty concisely with a regular expression. To come up with the string to deconstruct on index `n`, recursively call `countAndSay` to get the result of `n - 1`:

```js
let countAndSay = function (count) {
  if (count === 1) {
    return '1';
  }
  const digitsArr = countAndSay(count - 1).match(/(\d)\1*/g);
  // You now have an array of each chunk to construct
  // eg, from 1211, you get
  // ['1', '2', '11']
  return digitsArr // Turn the above into ['11', '12', '21']:
    .map(digitStr => digitStr.length + digitStr[0])
    .join(''); // Turn the above into '111221'
};
console.log(
  countAndSay(1),
  countAndSay(2),
  countAndSay(3),
  countAndSay(4),
  countAndSay(5),
);
```

Comment: Elegant sinppet!. Can you pls explain the role of `\1*` (in regex) why won't `\2*` or `\3*` work instead as they all would occur in the sequence?

Comment: That's a backreference. The `(\d)` matches a digit, and puts it in a capture group. That's the first (and only) capture group, so the syntax to match the same thing again is `\1`. To match *any number* of the same character that was matched in the capture group, put a `*` after it. `\2`, `\3` don't work because that syntax would match what was most recently matched by the 2nd or 3rd capture groups, but such groups don't exist in the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that generates the next string of numbers based on the previous string you feed it:

```
function next(s) {
    s = s + "*";  // add a flag value at the end of the string
    var output = "";
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i - 1)) { // if the character changes, concatenate the amount (i - j) and the digit
            output += (i - j) + s.substring(j, j+1);
            j = i;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Then you'd need to recursively run `next` N times.

Comment: @RahulChoudary my apologies

Comment: can you please run this program

Comment: can you please share `jsfiddle` or any editor link to verify output